# Remap only the scheme part of URIs

Tags: tcp, proxy, uri, mqtt

The mosquitto MQTT client builds URIs of the form mqtt://host:port or mqtts://host:port without an option to override the scheme part. The broker, however, accepts MQTT connections only under tcp://host:port or ssl://host:port. Is there a way to proxy mqtt:// to tcp:// and mqtts:// to ssl://?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make any change.

The client library interprets the scheme section internally, it is not presented to the broker in any form.

You just need to pick the right one for the version of the client you are using.